# How to pass query parameters through force_ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails 3.1 I am using force_ssl when authenticating. This seems to cause a problem when I have a redirect uri appended as a query string because it is stripped in the http -> https protocol switch. If I start on https protocol the query string stays intact and the redirect happens just fine.

Any ideas on how to preserve query strings through the force_ssl protocol switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of rails has it fixed https://github.com/rmm5t/rails/commit/391e6a47dbd46fdce0a472819e8d27792cc91984

If you have to use Rails 3.1 you will have to create your own force ssl before filter

```
before_filter :check_ssl

def check_ssl
  redirect_to({:protocol => 'https'}.merge(params), :flash => flash) unless request.ssl?
end
```